# How to create UI for adding a picture in a popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I am trying to add an identity proof in ionic app. When the user clicks on add proof button, a popup windows appears which has 2 fields

1. Select a photo.
2. Add Description.

So for selecting a picture, user has to browse the picture from file manager.
How to create this browser in a popup window?